# Replace rows based on a modified timestamp

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I am looking for an efficient method (which I can reuse for similar situations) to drop rows which have been updated.

My table has many columns, but the important ones are:

```
creation_timestamp, id, last_modified_timestamp
```

My primary key is the **creation_timestamp** and the **id**. However, after and id has been created, it can be modified by other users which is indicated by the **last_modified_timestamp**.

1) Read a daily file and add any new rows (based on creation_timestamp and id)

2) Remove old rows which have a different last_modified_timestamp and replace them with the latest versions.

I typically do most of my operations with Pandas (python library) and pyscopg2, so I am not extremely familiar with PostgreSQL 9.6 which is the database I am using. My initial approach is to just add the last_modified_timestamp to the primary key, and then just use a view to SELECT DISTINCT based on the latest changes. However, it seems like that is 'cheating' and I will be wasting space since I do not need to retain previous versions.

EDIT:

```
def create_update_query(df, table=FACT_TABLE):
    columns = ', '.join([f'{col}' for col in DATABASE_COLUMNS])
    constraint = ', '.join([f'{col}' for col in PRIMARY_KEY])
    placeholder = ', '.join([f'%({col})s' for col in DATABASE_COLUMNS])
    updates = ', '.join([f'{col} = EXCLUDED.{col}' for col in DATABASE_COLUMNS])
    query = f"""
    INSERT INTO {table} ({columns}) 
    VALUES ({placeholder}) 
    ON CONFLICT ({constraint}) 
    DO UPDATE SET {updates};"""
    query.split()
    query = ' '.join(query.split())
    return query

def load_updates(df, connection=DATABASE):
    conn = connection.get_conn()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    df1 = df.where((pd.notnull(df)), None)
    insert_values = df1.to_dict(orient='records')
    for row in insert_values:
        cursor.execute(create_update_query(df), row)
        conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    del cursor
    conn.close()
```

This appears to work. I was running into some issues, so right now i am looping through each row of the DataFrame as a dictionary, then inserting that row. Also, I had to figure out a way to fill in the nan columns with None, because I was getting errors with Timestamp dtypes with blank values, etc.

Comment: Why not just simply `UPDATE` the rows? Why do you want to do this `INSERT`+`DELETE` combination? (Which BTW is easy to get it wrong in a highly concurrent environment).

Comment: That would be better. I'll post my initial SQL (I haven't tried using UPSERT before)

Comment: I added my update query.. it appears to work, I still need to do some more testing.